# Can my Cleric with the Primordial Adept theme use his holy symbol for theme powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, implements, theme

The Primordial Adept theme, which gives rod proficiency and has Implement-keyword powers, mentions no restrictions or caveats to its powers' implement use. Do only rods work for Primordial Adept implement powers, or is the gaining of rod proficiency just a 'gimme' for classes with no implement proficincies that take the theme?

In other words, can my Cleric/Primordial Adept use his holy symbol for Primordial Adept powers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, assuming you're playing with the latest errata**

An implement proficiency now works with all powers that have the implement keyword, regardless of source. This was an important change in the errata and may be printed differently if you are relying on only the PHB. (Citation needed)